# PHP - I need a way to replace square brackets with dynamic data

Tags: php

I am trying to build a system which will allow the user to enter a certain amount of text in a textarea field, within the text entered, the user will enter a "variable" in the format [VAR], the text VAR will be replace by the "variable" the user needs such as [AMOUNT], which will query a database to find the amount for the user, i need a PHP script will find those square bracket variable and replace it by some dynamic data.

Can anybody help?

Regards,
Roddy

Comment: Do you have any code already?

Comment: You can use a templating engine, or PHP's native bbcode functions, or just simply do a pattern match & replace. Have you been to php.net yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```php
$vars = array(
    'username' => 'User1',
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
$text = "Hello, [username]! This is a test! [foo]";
foreach ($vars as $k => $v) $text = str_ireplace("[".$k."]", $v, $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Looks simple enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **PHP Template Engine**

You can use Smarty and I think it's very good choise and easy to learn and use

Documentation:

[Smarty Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/documentation)

Comment: won't work, the installation looks like i will need to have full access to the server, to install the libs.

Comment: No, you don't need to back to server, just follow installation instructions and it will work without any problem.